# RegExp properties (flags, source, etc) on the prototype or the instance?

Tags: javascript

I'm a little unclear on how RegExp objects are implemented in the ES spec even after reading the section on regular expression objects. I had assumed that all the properties (like flags, source, global, multiline) were instance properties since they contain data for a specific RegExp object, but MDN lists them as properties of the *prototype* instead.

How does that work? Are they defined as accessors on the prototype which check the value of hidden instance fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the spec is quite clear. The're [own properties of the RegExp instance](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.7), created [in the constructor](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.4.1).
Or at least, that's how it was in ES5. Since ES6, the properties are indeed [getters on the prototype](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-get-regexp.prototype.global) that access an <s>immutable</s> internal slot which is [initialised](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-regexpinitialize) from the constructor or `.compile()`. There's even [a note](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-properties-of-regexp-instances):

> Prior to ECMAScript 2015, ``` RegExp instances were specified as having the own data properties ``source ```, `global`, `ignoreCase`, and `multiline`. Those properties are now specified as accessor properties of RegExp.prototype.

So your assumption was well founded, but MDN is correct as well :-)

Comment: Right, I didn't realize I was reading the 5.1 edition of the spec, which doesn't talk about accessors on the prototype. I did read the part of about them inheriting the properties from the prototype, but I guess I misread it as saying the value is held on the prototype, which wouldn't make sense if they weren't methods. Reading the constructor spec would have cleared some of this up (though I'd have outdated information at this point). Thanks for clearing this up.

Answer (score 2):

This snippet pretty much answers your question:

```js
console.log(
  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(RegExp.prototype).filter(
    key => typeof Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(RegExp.prototype, key).get === 'function'
  )
)
```

The answer is yes, `RegExp.prototype` defines getters for each of the member values that looks up values from internal slots on the instance object. You could have also looked at the [ECMAScript specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-get-regexp.prototype.flags) to figure that out as well.

Comment: The 5.1 edition of the ES specification showed up in my search apparently, and was much less clear on that point. Thanks.